# Minimising Firebase realtime database traffic usage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase database to count rating of some items in my app. I have structure like this:

```
{
    "id_1": {
         "count" : -6
     },
    ... // 1498 ids here
    "id_1500": {
         "count" : -1
     }
}
```

When user watch item, I simple decrement related `count` value with `runTransaction` method.

I need to provide "top items" list to users. Now I use `queryOrderedByChild` ("count") and `queryLimitedToFirst` (100) to get top 100 objects. (I use negative counters because Firebase supports only ascending sort. So items with most negative `count` value will be first).

As I understand, querying database spends much more traffic than just putting new value. Is this really so? Or it still need to download the full contents of database even I want to update it?

I'm just learning, and it would be interesting for me not to climb beyond the limits of the free tariff plan. Not from the 'money" point of view, just want to optimize my solution with resources I have.

For example, as another solution, I can write script to export DB JSON every day/hour and provide link to it (using `Storage` api with larger limits). And show "top 100" list using this file (yes it's ok that it will be outdated for several hours/minutes sometimes).

Is this a good solution, or writing new values to the database will still consume a lot of my Realtime Database traffic? There is only "GB downloaded" field in Realtime Database prising, is this means that uploading (updating values) is always free and don't increase this traffic?